# Do I need to create an .xpi file to test my Firefox extension?

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, firefox-addon-webextensions, firefox-addon-bootstrap, firefox-addon-overlay

I have a Firefox extension. When I change the source code, every time I have to create the zip file including the source code and then make it as a *.xpi* file. Can I avoid this making `*.xpi` file steps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For all types of [Firefox extensions](https://web.archive.org/web/20170910014948/https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/firefox-addon/3235/getting-started-with-firefox-addon/13574/introduction#t=201709100149489262324) you can test your extension without the need to create an *.xpi* file for each iteration.

#### WebExtensions

- WebExtensions can be directly loaded as a [temporary extension](https://web.archive.org/web/20170910022241/https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/firefox-addon/3235/getting-started-with-firefox-addon/26613/installing-a-temporary-add-on#t=20170910022241247808) from the directory containing the *manifest.json* file. This is done from `about:debugging`.
- You can use [`web-ext run`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Getting_started_with_web-ext) to test your extension in a temporary profile.
- They can be installed as an unpacked extension (all files not in a *.xpi* file). In addition, you can use a [Firefox extension proxy file](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Setting_up_extension_development_environment#Firefox_extension_proxy_file) to have your extension files located in any directory you choose, not just under the profile's extensions directory.

#### Add-on SDK extensions

- You can use [`jpm run`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tools/jpm) to test your extension without directly dealing with the *.xpi* file.
- Add-on SDK extensions can **not** be loaded as temporary extensions without first explicitly creating the *.xpi* file with `jpm xpi`. However, as an *.xpi*, they can be loaded as temporary extensions.
- Add-on SDK extensions can not directly be loaded as unpacked extensions. You would need to package the extension first using `jpn xpi`, then manually unpacking the extension.

#### Bootstrap/Restartless extensions

- Bootstrap/Restartless extensions can be directly loaded as a [temporary extension](https://web.archive.org/web/20170910022241/https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/firefox-addon/3235/getting-started-with-firefox-addon/26613/installing-a-temporary-add-on#t=20170910022241247808) from the directory containing the *chrome.manifest* and *install.rdf* files. This is done from `about:debugging`.
- They can be installed as an unpacked extension (all files not in a *.xpi* file). In addition, you can use a [Firefox extension proxy file](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Setting_up_extension_development_environment#Firefox_extension_proxy_file) to have your extension files located in any directory you choose, not just under the profile's extensions directory.

#### Overlay/Legacy/XUL based extensions

- Overlay/Legacy/XUL based extensions can not be loaded as a [temporary extension](https://web.archive.org/web/20170910022241/https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/firefox-addon/3235/getting-started-with-firefox-addon/26613/installing-a-temporary-add-on#t=20170910022241247808).
- They can be installed as an unpacked extension (all files not in a *.xpi* file). In addition, you can use a [Firefox extension proxy file](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Setting_up_extension_development_environment#Firefox_extension_proxy_file) to have your extension files located in any directory you choose, not just under the profile's extensions directory.

### Additional information

I would suggest you read [Installing add-ons for development](https://web.archive.org/web/20170910020945/https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/firefox-addon/3235/getting-started-with-firefox-addon/27246/installing-add-ons-for-development#t=201709100209448888249) and [Installing a Temporary Add-on](https://web.archive.org/web/20170910022241/https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/firefox-addon/3235/getting-started-with-firefox-addon/26613/installing-a-temporary-add-on#t=20170910022241247808) which cover these issues in more detail.

Comment: Yes. [Web-ext-run](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Getting_started_with_web-ext) worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

With WebExtensions, you don't need to create the .xpi file. You can directly go to `about:debugging` in the address bar and load your temporary add-on file. You can also click on `debug` to debug your webExtension. Have a look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Temporary_Installation_in_Firefox) for more information on loading your first firefox add-on.